# how to send form data in request axios form data expect arr[]:value arr[]:value1 arr[]:value2

Tags: javascript, axios

```
let data = {
nama: "Test Keyos Ajah",
slogan: "apa aja deh gini",
domain: "dev.keyos.id",
provinsi: "Jawa Barat",
kota: "Kota Tasikmalaya",
kecamatan: "Indihiang",
alamat: "Disini ajah deh",
kurir: "JNE,TIKI,POS,JNT,SICEPAT,NINJA"
}
```

[current result in form data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6jC0.png)

how to resolving if iam want to result in form data

```
kurir[]:JNE
kurir[]:TIKI
kurir[]:POS
kurir[]:JNT
kurir[]:SICEPAT
kurir[]:NINJA
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i understand your question correctly, but:
If you want to send form data through axios, you can use the formdata Web API :

```js
let formData = new FormData();
```

and then you can use the append method to add your formdata entries :

```js
formData.append('nama', 'Test Keyos Ajah');
formData.append('kurir[]', 'JNE');
formData.append('kurir[]', 'TIKI');

etc...
```

and then to post your data, just use `data: formData` in your axios request.